# Using floating numbers for functions

Tags: c++, function

I ran this codes only my zybook class, it gives me the wrong answers and tells me to use floating numbers for the functions. How can I use floating point numbers for square function.

[image: This is the image for the output results]

edit:

sorry for the confusion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


float squareRoot( float s) { 

   float xn; 

   if (s == 0) { 
      xn = 0; 
      } 

   else { 

      xn = s / 2.0; 
      int counter = 1; 

      while (counter <= 10) { 
         xn = (xn + (s/ xn)) / 2.0; 
         counter = counter + 1;
         } 

      } 
      return xn;

   } int square(int what) { 
      return what* what; 

   } 

   int main() { 

      float sideA, sideB, sideC; 
      string answer = "yes"; 
      while (answer == "yes") { 
         cout <<" Enter side A: "; 
         cin >> sideA; 
         cout << sideA << endl; 
         cout <<" Enter side B: "; 
         cin >> sideB; 
         cout << sideB << endl; 
         sideC = squareRoot( square( sideA) + square( sideB)); 
         cout <<"Side C is " << sideC << endl; 
         cout <<"Continue? "; 
         cin >> answer; 
         cout << answer << endl; 
         } 
         return 0; 
      }
```

Comment: What? "to float the function" What do you mean?

Comment: what does it mean to "float a function" ?

Comment: Given that the example code dosen't show the types for sideA and sideB, how can we tell?

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question.

Comment: Ok what inputs are you using, and what answers do you get, and what answers do you expect?

Comment: `int square(int what) { return what* what; }` simply replace `int` with `float`

Comment: Thank you tobi303. I was changing only one int.

Answer (score 1):

Your function:

```
int square (int what){
 return what * what;
}
```

should instead return a float. When you pass the floating point numbers to this function, it returns them as integers so instead of 3.3 and 4.4 getting squared, 3 and 4 do.

You should return a float and change what to a float as well.